# Access denied to MYSQL, but I just created the rails app and the database.yml file looks fine?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am at a bit of a loss on this one. I created the rails app, installed the mysql bundle and checked my database.yml file. Everything seems on point, but I can't log in to MYSQL. I have tried mysql -u root. mysql -u root -p. mysqladmin -u as well. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My errors look like.

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

or

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Database.yml

```
  # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: InterCambios_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: InterCambios_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: InterCambios_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: You should have been asked to provide a MySQL root password during the installation, which is not the system's root user password. Is this password not working? Perhaps you had capslock on when you typed it? Maybe you should just reinstall, because you wont be getting this password back easily.

Comment: No password was asked as it was just bundled into the install. I am trying access locally. That said, I have created apps in the past on this machine with MYSQL and I got those to work. I wonder if that is the conflict.

Comment: Maybe you should uninstall it and delete the content of `/var/lib/mysql`, it will remove any remaining existance of old databases including the `mysql` that contains the users passwords. After that it should ask for a new password during installation, otherwise there will be none. But bewhere you will lose everything you had stored in MySQL.

Comment: You should reset your password http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, and use your new password in database.yml. I have had that problem before, but I don't know the root cause.